# trying to use continue or pass inside while loop but it doesnt seem to do work selenium

Tags: python, selenium, while-loop, continue, except

my program iterate between items, it clicks on the item, then clicks again and moves to the next item.
i am trying to make the program pass on an item if error accurs.

the excepts are inside a while loop, each item code seems like this:

```
item_1 = driver.find_element_by_id('feed_item_0')
    item_1.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    if item_1.is_displayed():
        item_1.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    phone_reveal_1 = driver.find_element_by_id('phone_number_0')
    contact_seller_1 = driver.find_element_by_id('contact_seller_0')
    if phone_reveal_1.is_displayed():
        phone_reveal_1.click()
    elif contact_seller_1.is_displayed():
        contact_seller_1.click()

    elif not phone_reveal_1.is_displayed() or contact_seller_1.is_displayed():
        continue
```

at the end i wrote this:

```
except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
    continue
except selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException:
    continue
except selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException:
    continue
```

so what the code does is when any error accurs no matter if continue, or pass is written, the loop starts all over again from the start. i just want it to skip the item what. am i missing?

Comment: may be the second `if` could be `elif`

Comment: thank you, it wont work beacuse its a new statement

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who will have the same issue, problem, was that i have handled the exceptions at the end. every block needs to have its own exception. the code should be like this:

```
try:

    item_1 = driver.find_element_by_id('feed_item_0')
    item_1.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    if item_1.is_displayed():
        item_1.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    phone_reveal_1 = driver.find_element_by_id('phone_number_0')
    contact_seller_1 = driver.find_element_by_id('contact_seller_0')
    if phone_reveal_1.is_displayed():
        phone_reveal_1.click()
    elif contact_seller_1.is_displayed():
        contact_seller_1.click()
    phone_numbers_1 = driver.find_elements_by_id('phone_number_0')
    number_1 = [i.text for i in phone_numbers_1]

except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
```